# Would an American-led, post-apocalyptic semi-dystopian “United States of North America” be just the US and Canada or would it also include Mexico?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, science-fiction, politics, geopolitics

For some context, my world takes place in a dystopian, post-apocalyptic time in 2045 where the human race was pushed to the brink of extinction and modern civilization collapsed due to Kaiju (or known in my world as Unidentified Colossal Organisms (UCOs)) rising up and laying waste to humanity. Godzilla (the strongest and most powerful organism on the planet) was directly responsible for killing over 850 million humans across all seven continents as well as conquering massive swaths of land and ocean in and around the Pacific Rim.

Legend (*original map of the United States of North America*):

- Land areas w/diagonal black slashes: the infamous Godzilla Continental Exclusion Zone (land that the former USA, Canada, (and Mexico in the second map) surrendered to Godzilla
- Black Line border: Continental Militarized Zone (CMZ); most heavily fortified and militarized strip of land on the planet, meant to defend against Godzilla and other UCOs
- Blue circles along the CMZ: Battle Stations (massive military fortresses that are meant to safeguard a specific sector against Godzilla and the UCOs)
- Blue squares: Command Battle Stations (oversees a particular region of the CMZ)
- Red spots: Cities and areas destroyed by Godzilla
- Black spot in Southern California: Owens Valley Nuclear Zone (place where Godzilla directly tanked and survived 250 nukes being dropped on him)

[image: Original idea for the United States of North America]

Comment: This seems opinion-based: Politics can be based on many factors -- you can have it work out any way that your story needs. My opinion is that Mexicans have put up with worse than Kaiju without surrendering their independence.

Comment: Well, it's planely obviously yes because of your map as published at the time of this comment - this is a yes/no question and opinion based. Are you asking "how" they might be involved, or "how might the large powers involve them"? - It strikes me as a writing decision, and therefore opinion based. Care to [edit] to ask an objective question?

Comment: @Rottweileronmarket-day. What I’m trying to ask is would it make sense to include Mexico on a political/geopolitical, economic, and societal scale.

Comment: The only way to answer this one is to write a few stories based on each premise and see which one you like the best.

Comment: 850 million people is about 12% of world population. Assuming this was distributed evenly, the US population is about 328 mn., so population loss in the US would be about 40 mn. If we consider that California is heavily populated compared to the mid-West, say 60 mn. people were killed. The major damage, I feel, would be the 250 nuclear weapons detonated over the San Andreas fault, which probably killed more people than Godzilla, and probably triggered the Yellowstone caldera. At this point, I don't think people would be too worried about national borders, rather than the volcanic winter

Comment: Let me point out that you asked this question the wrong way. The problem is that StackExchange requires questions to be asked in a way to produce objective answers with a narrow scope. By asking an "or" question, you violated that premise. You were correct to use the [tag:reality-check] tag, but the way the tag is meant to be used is you provide a complete scenario (no variations asked for) and ask for people to critique it in the context of your world's rules (which you must also provide). It's the difference between "could this happen?" and "did I do a good job?" The former is off-topic.

Comment: America just dropped 250 nukes on its own territory and you think CANADA would join with America?  Even less likely than Mexico joining the dystopia that is America.

Answer (score 1):

I think, given the context, it would make sense for it to be a full north American triad, to include Mexico. Boundaries in war very often defer to physical features, and it would be odd to have that arbitrary cut at the south end of California, where even on your own map it looks like they held the monsters to the west of the mountains, and so, the black slashed areas seems like it would naturally extend down Baja, and the coastal plains of western Mexico. Add to this the element of the collapse of modern civilization as you describe, and it again makes sense that instead of reforming with the horizontal border between the countries, you might instead end up with that common north south border that divides human from not human.